# code Not Running

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I am Getting a run time Exception  while using this code

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
System.out.println("Executing " + "uname -a");
Process x = rt.exec("ping IP Address of system");
BufferedReader stdInput =
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(x.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader stdError =
    new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(x.getErrorStream()));
String line = null;
while ((line = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
x.waitFor();
```

Comment: What exception are you getting precisely? And what is your question about it?

Comment: Could you paste the exception stacktrace?

Comment: I tried it on Windows 7 64bit, and it works just fine.

Comment: What is the question? Is `uname -a` and `ping` supposed to be the same?

Comment: See [When Runtime Process exec won't](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html). As said by others a bit more info would have been nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way..

```
public class PingClass {

    public void pingIt(){

        InetAddress addr;
        try {
            String line;

            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                    "C:/windows/system32/ping.exe 192.168.2.2");

            /**
             * Create a buffered reader from the Process' input stream.
             */
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p
                    .getInputStream()));

            /**
             * Loop through the input stream to print the program output into console.
             */
            ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                str.add(line);
                System.out.println(line);

            }
            /**
             * Finally close the reader
             */
            input.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   


    public static void main(String[] args){


        new PingClass().pingIt();
    }

}
```